# Google Drive: Application-Owned Accounts

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to make sure that I understand [Application-Owned Accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts) correctly, because it sounds to good to be true.

I have a shop, and I want to place all my products on my application drive account.
I want to be able to dynamically perform those actions:

- Add new products
- Delete products
- Update products
- Enjoy the drive file revisions

Do I get all those for free for all my 1,000,000 users?

What is the catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main drawback I think is that you cannot purchase additional space for service/application accounts. You can have the basic 15GB (at time of writing) but that this cannot be increased.

This is mentioned in the third paragraph on [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts)

I am using Google drive with my own user account (with expanded storage) via the API to store call recordings: I make the files available via my own website and I control the access so I could have a million users of my app, but use one Drive at the back end.

Comment: Are you sure there is no traffic limits? Because I saw private accounts been limited. The difference here that it's application account.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I think it's fairly clear on that page. There are only two types: regular and service. Service == Application.